# jQuery Mobile and .next() after DOM manipulation?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, touch

Ok so I have started using jQuery Mobiles pre-fetch abilities. I'm using the link method specified on this page http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html. The only problem is my swipe code fails to see the pages that were brought in via the pre-fetch. Please see this js fiddle for a working example of the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/UurQC/1/

Any one have any thoughts as to what to try to get .next to find the new pages. I have also tried targeting them via

```
div.ui-page
```

And it still comes up as an empty selector in firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are attempting to select the next DOM element, not the next pesueo-page element. Since you are adding the last page after the DOM loads, it's actually being added after another element (so `.next()` is selecting this other element instead of the pseudo-page).

I changed:

```
$(this).next("div:jqmData(role='page')");
$(this).prev("div:jqmData(role='page')");
```

To:

```
$(this).nextAll("div:jqmData(role='page')").first();
$(this).prevAll("div:jqmData(role='page')").first();
```

Which selects all the previous/next pseudo-pages and then selects just the first of those.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UurQC/2/

If you don't delegate the event handlers for the swipe events then the swipe event handlers won't run for the dynamically placed pseudo-page. Here's how to fix that:

```
$(document)
    .on("swipeleft", "div:jqmData(role='page')", function(){
        var $nextPage = $(this).nextAll("div:jqmData(role='page')").first();
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if ($nextPage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage($nextPage, { transition: 'slide' });
        }
    })
    .on("swiperight", "div:jqmData(role='page')", function(){
        var $prevPage = $(this).prevAll("div:jqmData(role='page')").first();
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if ($prevPage .length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage($prevPage, { transition: 'slide', reverse : true });
        }
    });
```

And here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UurQC/3/

**UPDATE**

Here is what the DOM looks like and why the above is necessary:

```
<div data-role="page" id="text_0" data-url="text_0" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 452px; "></div>
<div data-role="page" id="text_1" data-url="text_1"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="text_2" data-url="text_2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<div data-role="page" id="text_3" data-url="text_3"></div>
<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default"></div>
```

Note that this is not the full HTML but only the direct children of the `<body>` element.

Notice that the dynamically created pseudo-page is added to the DOM after JSFiddle added your JS code in a `<script>` tag. This will be an issue when not run on JSFiddle as well, as jQuery Mobile adds a loader element as it initializes.

Comment: Thanks that does work. So is .next only works on the DOM that was there when the page was first loaded? I'm a bit confused on that part as I figured .next would check the current DOM. Also any tips on handling code that is specific to a set of pages with say class demo?

Comment: @hcker2000 `.next()` only selects the immediate proceeding sibling element, so if you pass in a selector and the immediately next element doesn't match the selector, you just won't select anything. That's why there is a `.nextAll()` method that allows you to pass a selector that will only match certain siblings. `.nextAll()` and `.prevAll()` are nice because if you use `.siblings()` you have to do work on that list to detect which is closest to the current selection.

Comment: OK I understand now. Thanks for the extra info I'm not sure why I thought .next did what .nextAll does.